# Binding with ValueConverter not updating in UI after value change

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have this XAML

```
<Label
x:Name="lblStatus"
FontSize="Small"
LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
Text="{Binding ., Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='Status: {0}', Converter={views:JobStatusConverter}}" />;
```

I have JobViewModel binded into it.

I have used notify property change
OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(String.Empty));
in property setter but still not success.
Here is my converter

```
public class JobStatusConverter : IMarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is JobModel model)
        {
            if (!model.IsActive)
             {
                    return "Notactive";
            }
            if (model.IsDone)
            {
                return "Closed";
             }
        return "Open";
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;

public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;


public bool Invert { get; set; }
```

}

Here is my model code

```
    public class JobViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
    private JobModel Model { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive =>
        Model?.IsActive ?? false;

    public bool IsDone =>
        Model?.IsDone ?? false;

    public void ReceiveData()
    {
        try
        {
            Model = GetJobData("JB001");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(String.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

after calling ReceiveData() from command, all other UI values are updated but not lblStatus value
Why this is not working?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? Can you please elaborate!

Comment: @dymanoid, G.hakim i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

> An Empty value or null for the propertyName parameter indicates that
>   all of the properties have changed.

But you are not binding to any property but to the model itself. In your particular case you could bind to `IsActive`, change converter a bit and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** the `BindingContext` of Label is `JobViewModel`,not `JobModel` .So the logic in the convert will never been called.

Since you have used data-binding ,you can set the `Text` of Label in the `JobViewModel`.

```
Text={Binding Content}
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class JobViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string content;
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return content;
        }

        set
        {
            if (content != value)
            {
                content = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private JobModel Model { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive =>
        Model?.IsActive ?? false;

    public bool IsDone =>
        Model?.IsDone ?? false;

    public JobViewModel()
    {
        if (!Model.IsActive)
        {
            Content = "Status:Notactive";
        }
        if (Model.IsDone)
        {
            Content = "Status:Closed";
        }
        Content = "Status:Open";
    }

}
```